# Filtering List without using iterator

Tags: java, collections, guava

I need to filter a List of size 1000 or more and get a sublist out of it. 
I dont want to use an iterator.

1) At present I am iterating the List and comparing it using Java. This is time consuming task. I need to increase the performance of my code.

2) I also tried to use Google Collections(Guava), but I think it will also iterate in background.

```
  Predicate<String> validList = new Predicate<String>(){  
      public boolean apply(String aid){  
          return aid.contains("1_15_12");  
      }  
  }; 
   Collection<String> finalList =com.google.common.collect.Collections2.filter(Collection,validList);
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I get sublist faster without iterating or if iterator is used I will get result comparatively faster.

Comment: 1000 is not a very big number. And it being a list with sequential access, iteration is unavoidable afaik.

Comment: I think iterator is inevitable during filtering, as each element has to be checked.

Comment: @Nivas: Your comment should be an answer

Comment: @Jim Garrison, in hindsight, yes. But as others have answered with the same, I refrain. Doesn't add much value now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if you call `size()` on your sublist. That *has* to check every element, as every element may change the result.

If you have a very specialized way of *using* your list which means you don't touch every element in it, don't use random access, etc, perhaps you don't want the `List` interface at all. If you could tell us more about what you're doing, that would really help.

Comment: @Gabriel: I think it *is* an answer: if he needs the general interface of List, he won't be able to do better than iterating over the whole list. If he *doesn't* need the whole of the `List` interface, he could use a different interface which may be feasible without iterating.

Comment: Theoretically that is not entirely true. Depending on the use (as you wrote) he can use List with Constraints, add to List in particular order etc. to prevent the need for iterating the whole Collection and stay with List. But it depends, I wouldn't give such an answer, I would make it a comment to get more information and answer afterwards, to give him a solution to his problem. As this is subjective, I take back my downvote (if you edit).

Comment: @Gabriel: I don't see how you can get away from the need for `size()` to examine every element. Either way, I view this as an answer as much as yours is: it states why you can't *in general* get away without examining every element (as per an iterator) and gives a suggestion for further though: namely thinking about what the OP actually needs from the result.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the `size()` argument. ArrayList and LinkedList remember their sizes in a field, which is updated in every size-changing operation. The `size()` method just returns the value of that field, it examines nothing. Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

List is an ordered collection of objects. So You must to iterate it in order to filter.

Answer (score 0):

I enrich my comment:
I think iterator is inevitable during filtering, as each element has to be checked.

Regarding to `Collections2.filter`, it's different from simple filter: the returned `Collection` is still "Predicated". That means `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if unsatisfied element is added to the `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is really your concern, most probably the predicate is pretty slow. What you can do is to Lists.partition your list, filter in parallel (you have to write this) and then concatenate the results.

There might be better ways to solve your problem, but we would need more information about the predicate and the data in the List.